# Difference in probability density function of Normal distribution when the mean is changed

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, change-of-variable

I have Normal distribution N(a,b). When I change it to N(c,b), the values of probability density function naturally change. Is is possible to write the change analytically? Is the a function of the difference (c-a)?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You can divide one density by the other and get something something relatively simple, but clearly this ratio will be a function of $x$ as well as $a,b,c$